# Inconsistency between int and bool

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I just implemented breadth first search in c++ and instead of declaring a vector as `bool`, I declared it as an `int`. This lead to a very odd observation. When I used `int`, the code printed the following:

```
1
32763
-524268732
```

Throughout the entire code, I don't provide any such value to variable as the 2nd and 3rd node receive, so I assume that they are just garbage values, but why do garbage values even come up, when I'm initialising the vector to be full of zeroes ??? You may check the code to be that below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

queue<int> neigh;
vector< vector<int> > graph(3);
vector<int> flag(3, 0);

int main(void)
{
    graph[0].push_back(1); graph[0].push_back(2);
    graph[1].push_back(0); graph[1].push_back(2);
    graph[2].push_back(0); graph[3].push_back(1);
    neigh.push(0);
    while(!neigh.empty())
    {

        int cur = neigh.front();
        neigh.pop();
        flag[cur] = 1;

        for(int i = 0, l = graph[cur].size();i < l;i++)
        {
            if(!flag[graph[cur][i]])
                neigh.push(graph[cur][i]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        cout << flag[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Alright, then I changed just a single line of code, line number 7, the one where I declare and initialise the `flag` vector.

Before:

```
vector<int> flag(3, 0);
```

After:

```
vector<bool> flag(3, false);
```

And voila! The code started working:

```
1 //The new output
1
1
```

So, my question is, what is the problem with the code in the first place ? I believe it may be some kind of error I made, or possibly that its only by chance that my bfs implementation works at all... So, what is the truth, SO? What is my (possible) mistake ?

Comment: Well, its a valid mistake, isn't it ? You SO guys with huge repos think you can go on down voting each and every question posted by a newbie ?

Comment: It is customary to at least leave a comment explaining the downvote. I don't see a problem with this question, so in return I'll upvote it for you to cancel the unexplained downvote. :-)

Comment: Also, may I suggest marking @juanchopanza's answer as accepted if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing your vector out of bounds here:

```
graph[3].push_back(1);
```

At this moment, `graph` only has three elements. This leads to *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Oh ****, sorry my bad, my real bad